# How to paste date on desire format Android?

Tags: android, simpledateformat

What I am trying to do is get the correct date format in a String.

I got it like this: 2020-05-13T22:00:52+0000

The desire one would be May-13-2020

I tried this:

```
Date date = new Date();
String insuranceRequestDate = formatDate.format(date);
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",Locale.getDefault());
//java.util.Date date1 = null;
try
{
        date = form.parse(insuranceRequestDate);
}
catch (ParseException | java.text.ParseException e)
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy",Locale.getDefault());
String newDateStr = postFormater.format(date);
```

But I get an error: 
`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020-05-13T22:00:52+0000" (at offset 19)`.

Any help or suggestions would be great. By the way, I can´t understand the answers to other questions in case you wonder if there are similar questions, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX"
```

instead of

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

- yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:SSXX => 2020-04-26T22:12:38+0200
- yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:SS.SSS => 2020-04-26T22:12:38.226

So you are getting **ParseException**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solved it actually with a much simpler solution: Date date = new Date();
                        String insuranceRequestDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);

Answer (score 0):

I solved it actually with a much simpler solution:

```
Date date = new Date();
String insuranceRequestDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
```